# Using Accuracy to evaluate clustering performance

Tags: machine-learning, classification, clustering, accuracy

Can I use accuracy, sensitivity, specificitity, positive predictive value, negative predictive value when i'm doing unsupervised classification (clustering) or do I have to limit my clustering evaluation to average silhouette width?

if you wonder how come I'm talking about accuracy while working on clustering, it's just because i have the actual real labels of all my subjects (healthy and sick) and I just want to see how well the clustering predicted the real labels with a specific variable.

And please, if you have other relevant evaluation criteria do not hesitate!

Answer (score 2):

Let the classes have labels "healthy" and "sick".

If you run kmeans, you get clusters labeled 0,1,2,3,4

How would you compute any of these measures?

There are plenty of evaluation measures for clustering. They are related to classification measures, but not the same, for a reason... Use the clustering measures for cluster evaluation and the classification evaluation measures for classification evaluation.

The two most popular cluster evaluation measures seem to be ARI and NMI.

Comment: Could you provide references or links for the measures you recommend?

Comment: @Anony-Mousse If I run kmeans with k=2 so the predicted clusters labels are: 0 and 1. Then, I just decide that "healthy"= 0 and "sick"=1, then I have the confusion matrix (predicted clusters VS real clusters). and with the confusion matrix I can have the true positives, true negatives, false positives, false negatives and so I can calculate the accuracy... No?

Comment: What if they are the other way around? Or you need to use k=5 because some clusters are just single nose points? Use ARI and NMI as in Wikipedia and any good clustering tutorial.

Answer (score 1):

There is a **major underlying hypothesis** in your process. You are indeed assuming that the clustering returns two distinct groups, and **each of them should corresponds to your labels**, which may not be the case.

Keep in mind that **clustering is a label-free process**. The two groups and especially their labels may vary depending on the initialization. Your process needs to identify which one represents (supposedly) healthy subjects, and which one should represents sick subjects, regardless of the label returned by the clustering.

Assuming that you have tackled this issue and identified who is who (say for instance, by looking at the group with highest proportion of truly sick subjects), you can indeed measure the accuracy of the model that you have created with the metrics you have mentioned. All metrics that can be applied to binary classification are relevant here. The **biggest issue** relies in the technique used to **assign the right label** to the groups created by your clustering.

Comment: Keep in mind, though: 1. identifying which cluster correponds to which class basically turns your cluster analysis into a classification. 2. Measuring accuracy etc. on the initially clustered data set  corresponds to a training error. It is intrinsically biased (in an optimistic way): when correlating clusters with labels, you already exclude the possibility that a classifier can be totally off (worse than guessing). You need to assess the naive guessing accuracy etc. for your method of assigning labels to clusters.

Comment: thank you also to @cbeleites
What do you suggest?

Comment: @cbeleites Totally agreed. I was making the assumption that the initial method used to build the model was based on clustering, and that they had a relevant method to turn it into classification (which is in any case necessary when predicting something else than the training set). The whole point of my post was to underline how critical is the method used for clustering-classification mapping.

Comment: So as conclusion I can't use accuracy in this case I have to use the classical measures for clustering quality: Rand Index, silhouette width etc...?

Comment: It depends if your final goal is purely descriptive (e.g. clustering to discover new patterns) or predictive (e.g. turn your clustering into classification). In the first case, accuracy is irrelevant. In the second case, it is relevant to keep it.

Comment: My goal is to prove that the variable ("BL") i am using to classify the two group is a very good marker (i.e. it has the power to tell us if the subject is sick or not)

Comment: Then you are, like you are saying, performing a *classification*. So all the metrics that apply to binary classification  (accuracy, confusion matrix...) are valid. The way you built your classifier may be confusing as you used a *clustering* technique to built it, but the end usage remains a classification problem.

Comment: I used the word classify in general (it also can be an unsupervised classification).